# correct use of TransportClient for elasticsearch

Tags: java, spring, elasticsearch

I have a problem with creating the TransportClient bean for elastic search the compiller it says that the constructor is private, and it is like that. How i can correctly create the bean?
Here is my config class:

```
import org.elasticsearch.client.Client;
import org.elasticsearch.client.transport.TransportClient;
import org.elasticsearch.common.transport.InetSocketTransportAddress;
import org.elasticsearch.common.transport.TransportAddress;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.ElasticsearchOperations;
import org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.ElasticsearchTemplate;
import org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.repository.config.EnableElasticsearchRepositories;

@Configuration
@EnableElasticsearchRepositories(basePackages = "example.spring.data.es.repository")
@ComponentScan(basePackages = { "example.spring.data.es.service" })
public class Config {

@Bean
public Client client() {
//here compiller says that the TransportClient() is private. How else i cna create the transport client?
    TransportClient client = new TransportClient();

    TransportAddress address = new InetSocketTransportAddress(
            "localhost",9200);
    client.addTransportAddress(address);
    return client;
}

@Bean
public ElasticsearchOperations elasticsearchTemplate() {
    return new ElasticsearchTemplate(client());
}
```

}

The elastic search dependency is: elasticsearch-2.4.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the provided builder methods for initialization. Example:

```
TransportClient client = TransportClient.builder().build();
```

Comment: indeed, ty, i found it that too. I was very intrigued because i found that example on the net that claimed it works, and i though at the beginning that i don't have the right jar dependency. Thank you for the answer.

Comment: Not working with Elasticsearch 5.6

Answer (score 9):

The API has changed! Be careful with the version you are using.

From [Version 5.5 Transport Client](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-api/5.5/transport-client.html):

```
TransportClient client = new PreBuiltTransportClient(Settings.EMPTY)
```

Note that you have to set the cluster name if you use one different than "elasticsearch":

```
Settings settings = Settings.builder().put("cluster.name", "myClusterName").build();
TransportClient client = new PreBuiltTransportClient(settings);
```